# Derived, boundary and interior of $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

Please verify if what I did is correct, I'm insecure specially at the derived part.

$A = [0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$

$A \subseteq \mathbb{Q} \implies A^0 \subseteq \mathbb{Q}^0 = \emptyset \implies A^0 = \emptyset$ ($\mathbb{Q}^0$ is empty because any ball centered in a rational contains irrational points, by density)

$\overline{A}=\overline{[0,1]}\cap\overline{\mathbb{Q}}=[0,1]\cap\mathbb{R}=[0,1]$

$\partial A = \overline{A} \setminus A^0 = [0,1] \setminus \emptyset = [0,1]$

$A' = \overline{A} \setminus A = [0,1] \setminus ([0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}) = [0,1] \cap (\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q})$

But if I take a rational $r \in [0,1]$, wouldn't any ball centered at it have nonempty intersection with $[0,1]$ and in different points than $r$, because of the density again? I'm confused...

Thanks.

Comment: I thought about it and now I think this is not correct: $A' = \overline{A} \setminus A$

Comment: Is $A'$ meant to be the set of limit points?

Comment: Yes, $A'$ is the derived set of $A$, which is the set of limit points.

Comment: I'm finding very odd that this question didn't get answers... I thought this was very elementary.

Comment: Every element of $\mathbb{R}$ is a limit of rational numbers.

Comment: @Joe, so the derived set of A would be $[0,1]$? Then it is false that derived set equals closure minus the set, right?

Comment: That depends on the definition given. Sometimes the definition excludes elements of the set, other times it doesn't. What's your given definition?

Comment: this one https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_set_(mathematics)